# HTML 5 offline applicatin manifest content type

Tags: html, manifest, cache-manifest

I am creating HTML 5 offline application example.
I choose manifest file like this :

```
<html manifest="Configuration/WMP.manifest">
```

and manifest file is like this :

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Build 2012-02-03

CACHE:
source/styles/examples-offline.css
source/styles/examples.css
source/js/Custom.js
source/js/jquery.min.js
source/js/people.js
source/index.html

NETWORK:
http://*
https://*
```

- Done correctly ?
- How do I check that sample works right in my local system ?
- I read that a manifest file must be served with the mime-type text/cache-manifest. where should I set this mime-type for manifest file ? I use basic HTML file and I don't use IIS or Apache webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
NETWORK:
http://*
https://*
```

This would try to match the exact URL `http://*`, which is an invalid URL.

You can only use the `*` character as a wildcard when it’s on its own line. For example, this would match any resource that hasn’t been explicitly listed under the `CACHE` or `FALLBACK` directives:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

---

Make sure you’re serving the file with the `text/cache-manifest` content type. This used to be explicitly required by the specification, and current browsers have it implemented that way.

> I use basic HTML file and I don't use IIS or Apache webserver

Then what do you use to serve up the file? Are you reading it locally, through the `file://` scheme?

---

To confirm everything is working, open up the page in Chrome, for example, and look at the Console.

---

By the way, there’s a validator for application cache manifests: http://manifest-validator.com/